# cellForRowAtIndexPath is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode6

I have a table view controller in which the cells don't show up:
I have added UiViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate as shown below:

```
myViewController:UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

In the storyboard as well as in the code I have set

```
self.tableView.delegate =self;
self.tableview.datasource = self;
```

My numberOfRowsInSection returns the value 30 (verified with logs) and numberOfSectionsInTableView returns 1 (verified with logs)

I have also printed the tableView header and footer view frame,height and width and they all have the value 0.0000

```
NSLog(@"The header frame size is%f" ,self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"The header frame size is%f" ,self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"The header frame size is%f" ,self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"The header frame size is%f" ,self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame.size.width);
```

This is the firstController of a navigation controller.
The numberOfSectionsInTableView method is called first, then the numberOfRowsInSection and then the  heightForRowAtIndexPath is called.

The cellForRowAtIndexPath method contains:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell configureCustomCell:[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

configureCustomCell configures the different properties in the cell.

I tried all the solutions given in similar questions but none of them seem to be working. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not being called after `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: Can you print the size of your table view like you did with the header & footer? Are the values also all 0?

Comment: I've put a breakpoint at all the methods, the code never reaches the breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I'm guessing that you never size your table view. Your table view will only try to load as many cells as can fit in the table view. If your size is `(0, 0)` then it won't try to render any cells.

Comment: You mean just tableHeaderView.frame.size and tableFooterView.frame.size?

Comment: How do I size my tableView?

Comment: Instead of `NSLog(@"The header frame size is%f" ,self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height);` do `NSLog(@"The table view frame size is%f" ,self.tableView.frame.size.height);` and for width as well.

Comment: tableView.frame.size.height is 200 and the tableView.frame.size.width is 320

Comment: Odds are that `numberOfRowsInSection:` is returning zero.

Comment: The numberOfRowsInSection: is returning 30.

Comment: Odds are that `numberOfRowsInSection:` is *actually* returning zero.

Comment: Why are you defining the protocols in your header, e.g. UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource? And why are you setting the delegate and datasource? It says you're using a UITableViewController, all this is setup for you. Odds are you've got some confused setup going. When using a UITableViewController, minimal setup is required regarding setting delegates etc

Comment: There's also the chance that you misspelled the name of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: ^ It can't be that because it's a required method so the app would crash, not just show 0 cells.

Comment: @AdamPro13 - Not if the OP extended UITableViewController.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that. I'm so used to just using a normal view controller with a table view as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

if you have configured `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols inside your ViewController.h file, then there is no need to use `self.tableView.delegate =self;`

```
self.tableview.datasource = self;
```

if you have configured UITableView inside your storyboard.
you need to configure your `CustomTableViewCell` with your `tableView's` cell property.

[image]
step - 1 
     select your tableView Cell and inside identity inspector define your CustomTableViewCell class.

[image]

step - 2 
     now provide cell identifier. (i have used "customCell")

[image]

import your CustomCell class inside your ViewController.m file. Just created demo app as per your reference. Hope it solves your query.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h" //CustomTableViewCell class

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30; //used staticCells 30
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customCell"; //as defined in cell identifier (as per step -2)

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    // configure your custom cell 

    return cell;

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Of course there is a need to use `self.tableView.delegate = self; self.tableView.dataSource = self;`. TableView is not capable of telepathy. If you don't set `delegate` and `dataSource` somehow (via Storyboard, or via code), it will never know. I've just checked it in an empty project just in case I missed some new features. It doesn't work if you don't set them explicitly.

Comment: yeah you are correct programmatically configuring UITableView requires 
self.tableView.delegate = self; 
self.tableView.dataSource = self;

but if we are using storyboard and configured UITableView then there is no need. I am doing same stuffs in my projects. :)

Comment: Yes, I see now, that the OP said, that he/she said it both in storyboard and programmatically. I was confused by the phrase `if you have configured UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols inside your ViewController.h file, then there is no need...`, because it doesn't mention storyboards, so without the context it is incorrect. Could you please correct it a little bit to avoid confusion?

Comment: @FreeNickname - Yeah sure !
Thanks to mention it. :)